# Exact date calculator

Tags: php

Is there a way of calculating the EXACT date after/before 6 months in Php taking into consideration the dynamic change in the days of the month i.e. consider some months have 30 days and some have 31 and 28 of course. I know it can be done with MySQL but I want to know if there is an option with Php as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use DateTime class: it takes leap years, DST and all problems in consideration for you.

Comment: Read documentation: http://php.net/DateTime

Comment: What do you consider the exact date if the base date is 30th March and you subtract 1 month? What date should you get then?

Answer (score 1):

you need to `date_create`, `date_interval_create_from_date_string` and `date_format` to complete the job.

```
$date = date_create('2000-01-01');
date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('6 months'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d'); // 2000-07-01
```

With Object Oriented:

**Adding**

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P6M'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n"; // 2000-07-01
```

**Subtracting**

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P6M'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n"; // 1999-07-01
```

Comment: Still doesn't show exact date. If I change 6 months to 1 month it shows 24th June whereas it should show 23rd June.

Comment: @Dev - Personally I'd expect it to show 24th June (today is 24th May), what timezone is your server in? (or what is your default timezone setting for your PHP?)

Comment: @MarkBaker, I am looking for real difference, Is it possible to make real difference?

Comment: It's still 23rd June in Hawaii for over an hour still, though there's not many parts of the world left on yesterday - [date_default_timezone_set('US/Hawaii')](https://3v4l.org/db8aq)

Comment: The thing is it should take into consideration the 31 days for May and similarly the 30 days for June when calculating the final date.

Comment: @Dev - So why exactly should 24th May + 1 month be 23rd June? Are you expecting it to add the number of days in the resulting month (ie 30 days.... that's adding days, not adding months)..... and what (for example) would you expect the result of adding 1 month to the 31st of May?

Comment: Yes, technically it is adding months but taking into consideration the number of days in the month.

Comment: What difference does the number of days in the month make? You're basically saying it's all wrong, but not explaining how you believe the logic should work..... __why__ should 24th May + 1 month give 23rd June rather than 24th June?

Answer (score 0):

get date before 6 month from current month:

```
echo date("F 1, Y", strtotime("-6 months"));
```

Comment: All good, except for that boring `1`. What is that for? it voids the basic requirement that they have. Exactly 6 months ago was *November 24, 2015* and not *November 1, 2015*.

Comment: The above code doesn't take into consideration the exact dates. Have already checked.